How to write Unit test case for viewmodel which contains SharedFlow?
Unit Testing SharedFlow inside a ViewModel
I'm trying to write unit test cases for my ViewModel. My ViewModel is like this
ScreenVM (val someClass : SomeClass()): ViewModel {

    private val _eventFlow: MutableSharedFlow<ScreenEvent> = MutableSharedFlow()

    val eventFlow = _eventFlow.asSharedFlow()

    fun doSomething(){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            when(someClass.getEvents()){
                is Success-> { _eventFlow.emit(Event1) }
                is Failure-> { _eventFlow.emit(Event2) }
            }
        }
    }

    sealed class ScreenEvent() {

        object Event1 : ScreenEvent()
        object Event2 : ScreenEvent()

    }

}

I'm trying to write Unit Test cases for the function doSomething() for the scenario when Event1 is emitted. I have experience with unit testing but I'm having issues as this a SharedFlow and it has a replayCache of 0 by default hence I can't use first() or similar operators to get the value.Any code example will be really helpful, thanks .
When I try to call first() it is not working as sharedflow does not retain state.
How should I write test case which contains sharedFlow in the viewmodel?

You create a list and pass it into the flow like so
@Test
fun flowTest() = runTest {
    val values = mutableListOf<ScreenEvent>()
    val collectJob = launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {
        vm.eventFlow.toList(values)
    }

    vm.doSomething()
   
    Assert.assertTrue(values[0])

    collectJob.cancel()
}

that list gets populated by what was emitted and you check the list for values. You might have to turn your doSomething function into a suspend method and remove the viewModelScope.launch because it might not launch the scope in time for the check

Not working!
vm.eventFlow.toList(values) is not called and the values list is always empty.

@MohitTrivedi Did you try changing you function to a suspend one and removing the viewModelScope like I suggested? You can read all about testing flows here https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#continuous-collection I use this exact way when I have to test flows and it works fine
